# Is it possible to run parallel tests using karma

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

At the moment we have close to 1000 unit tests written in jasmine/typescript.
When I run them all they take as much as 5 mins on chrome.  We do have some  unit tests which deals with DOM as well. e.g. verify if a button exists with specified text.
We have a number of files where these tests are distributed. We have noticed that when we run individual files and sum up total time taken, it is far less than that of when we run all tests in one go. That's why we are thinking if there is a way to run tests in parallel? The plan is to divide tests and run them in parallel.

Comment: Do you know what is causing them to take so long? We currently have 1021 unit tests in one of our projects and it takes less than a minute to run them. `1021 tests completed Finished 'ts-unit-tests' after 43 s`. Sounds like you should look into optimizing your tests.

Comment: Ours is an angular2 project with 50+ components and 20+ services. We do have some unit tests which deals with basic UI as well and for sure loads templates with often heavy html.

Comment: You're not the only one who would like parallel tests :-) https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/439

Answer (score 29):

You can use [karma-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-parallel) to split up your tests across multiple browser instances. It runs specs in different browser instances and is very simple and easy to install:

`npm i karma-parallel`

and then add the 'parallel' to the frameworks list in karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['parallel', 'jasmine']
  });
};
```

[karma-parallel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-parallel)

Disclosure: I am the author

Comment: Thank you Joel for your input. I have started a workaround now. Now I can run 2500 tests under 3 mins. So we are good. BTW, out of curiosity, have you tested your package for huge number of tests? Specially test related to components?

Comment: The project I built this for has about 5000 tests. It completes them all in about 20 seconds, on a Macbook Pro. Not sure quite what you mean by "related to components".

Comment: Is your project an angular 2 project? If not then you might want to try an angular 2 project. Other projects were not that problematic. Angular 2 component related tests are a mess due to the requirement that we have to compile and build test module before each tests.

Comment: Instead of building and compiling before each tests, I am doing so at the beginning of each file.

Comment: Interesting. No, I am not using an Angular 2 project, however, I would guess that it would still speed up your test execution by offloading to multiple browsers in the background. And good thought with precompiling them once for each component. That makes sense

Comment: The problem is with not alone with angular alone.. I have tried building parallel tests execution myself, these angular tests end up eating too much memory that execution on browser gets exponentially slower with each tests. First test at the beginning of my execution takes milli seconds.. While exact same test, if put at last takes 1 minute and browser memory reaches in GBs. I would really encourage you to try it on an angular 2 project.. May be you will be our savior.

Comment: TypeScripter, that might also signify a memory leak on your end, not necessarily karma's fault. I'm also looking for a solution, but just wanted to point this out to you in case you wanted to check your code for this.

Comment: I definitely agree that high memory consumption *could* be a user-error memory leak. I am not a angular+ dev, but if there are issues with memory consumption, you could theoretically use my karma-parallel plugin and set the executors to a very high number, and then set the 'concurrency' value that karma supports to a much lower level, perhaps 4. this would essentially enable "clearing" the global context frequently though out the test execution. Does that make any sense?

Comment: This does not work for me - I'm using karma, and jasmine to run some react unit tests...

Comment: This is really cool. Is it possible to ensure that the sharding isnt split between spec files? Im sure my tests are failing due to some silly shared state, but ive been cleaning such smells for 3 hours now and its tiring.

Comment: You can wrap all the test in a file in a describe. They won’t be split up from that describe.

Comment: The problem of memory leaking could be Mocha related (not sure about Jasmine).  In each test file I declare vars globally in the first/outer describe, then after the declaration I have an afterAll that sets each var to null.   This releases the memory of test vars.   I think the issue is that the runner attaches test results to the tests themselves, causing them and their vars to be referenced up till the end of the test.  A null var will get GC'd though.

Comment: I've used this on an Angular project with 20k+ tests and its saved us about 70% of our execution time locally and in CI. Awesome package